# ¿Cómo hacer una subconsulta select con dos parámetros de entrada?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subconsultas

quiero hacer una subconsulta con 2 parámetros.

Tengo 2 campos que quiero seleccionar dependiendo de X. Donde X va ser una consulta.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA1 T1 WHERE T1.CAMPO1 = X AND T1.CAMPO2 = X
```

Entiendo que podría hacer algo como:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA1 T1 WHERE T1.CAMPO1 IN (SELECT T2.CAMPO1 FROM TABLA2 T2) AND T1.CAMPO2 IN (SELECT T2.CAMPO2 FROM TABLA2 T2)
```

Pero, ¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo todo de una? ¿Sin hacer 2 veces el select? Algo tipo:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA1 T1 where (T1.CAMPO1, T1.CAMPO2) in (SELECT T2.CAMPO1, T2.CAMPO2 from TABLA2 T2)
```

o, tipo:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA1 T1 where (T1.CAMPO1 = T2.CAMPO1, T1.CAMPO2 = T2.CAMPO2) 
SELECT T2.CAMPO1, T2.CAMPO2 from TABLA2 T2
```

Answer (score 1):

**Subconsultas o JOIN**

Yo en tu lugar usaría JOIN en vez de subconsultas, claro depende de cuantos registros son los que componen la tabla es sabido que las subconsultas que usan `IN` son más lentas, en todo caso el optimizador de MySQL convierte en JOIN's la subconsultas que puede.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como quedaría tu consulta usando JOIN:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLA1 T1
JOIN TABLA2 T2 ON
    T1.CAMPO1 = T2.CAMPO1
    AND T1.CAMPO2 = T2.CAMPO2
```

Comment: Gracias, ¿pero si quiero hacer un Update? UPDATE TABLA SET (A,B) = (SELECT A,B FROM...) ¿Se podría hacer?

Comment: Esa es otra pregunta, pero si, eso se puede hacer.